# Share data between an external function and a python class function

Tags: python, function

I want to share a variable value between a function defined within a python class and an externally defined function.  So in the code below, when the internalCompute() function is called, self.data is updated. How can I access this updated data value inside a function that is defined outside the class, i.e inside the report function?
**Note:
  I would like to avoid using of global variable as much as possible.**

```
   class Compute(object):

      def __init__(self):
         self.data = 0

       def internalCompute(self):
          self.data = 5

   def externalCompute():
      q = Compute()
      q.internalCompute()

   def report():
      # access the updated variable self.data from Compute class
      print "You entered report"

   externalCompute()
   report()
```

Comment: Your example is a little too abstract, as it's not clear why `externalCompute` even exists. You probably just want to pass the appropriate `Compute` object to `report` as an argument. `q = Compute(); q.internalCompute(); report(q)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to avoid magic globals, but your `report()` function must have *some* way to know where to look. If it's ok to pass it the object doing the computation, i.e. `q`, it can simply print out `q.data`. If not, then you can arrange for `q` to save its data in the class itself-- obviously this means that the class can only be instantiated once, so I would go with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that unless you instantiate the class somewhere.
Currently in your implementation you instantiate the Compute class here:

```
def externalCompute():
  q = Compute()
  q.internalCompute()
```

But as soon as the function finishes **q** goes out of scope and is destroyed so you will lose all information that the class contains. In order to do what you want to do the **Compute** class has to be instantiated to not be local to a function (or your function needs to return the instance of the **Compute** class as to preserve its state.)

Usually you would do that by having one "main" if your python file in this way:

```
   class Compute(object):

      def __init__(self):
         self.data = 0

       def internalCompute(self):
          self.data = 5

   def externalCompute(q):
      q.internalCompute()

   def report(q):
      # access the updated variable self.data from Compute class
      data = q.data
      print "You entered report"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   q = Compute()
   externalCompute(q)
   report(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have access to the data through `q.data`, you just have to return it.

Change your code to reflect that fact:

```
 class Compute(object):

    def __init__(self):
       self.data = 0

    def internalCompute(self):
       self.data = 5

    def externalCompute():
       q = Compute()
       q.internalCompute()
       return q.data

    def report():
       print externalCompute()

    report() # 5
```

If you don't like this approach, you have only a few other options:

- Global variable.
- Instantiating another class.
- Updating the same class you instantiated.
- Database.
- Pickle.